# Showing the partial derivative of Lagrangian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, euler-lagrange-equation

I got the Lagrangian equation
$$L(q,\dot{q})=T-V=\frac{1}2m|(\dot{\textbf{q}}+\textbf{S}(\omega)\textbf{q})|^2-V(\textbf{Rq})$$

where S and R are 3x3 matrices. I have to show that

$$\frac{\partial L(\textbf{q},\dot{\textbf{q}})}{\partial \dot{\textbf{q}}}=m(\dot{\textbf{q}}+\textbf{S}(\omega)\textbf{q})$$
$$\frac{\partial L(\textbf{q},\dot{\textbf{q}})}{\partial \textbf{q}}=-m\textbf{S}(\dot{\textbf{q}}+\textbf{S}(\omega)\textbf{q})-\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{q}}V(\textbf{Rq})$$

I am told that it might be convenient to go into coordinates, i.e., work out the k'th Euler-Lagrange equation.

In the first partial derivative it seems that $-V(\textbf{Rq})$ disapears when we take the partial derivative with respect to $\dot{\textbf{q}}$ and i would have guessed that we had to use the chain rule for the squared part but it seems that isnt necessary?

For the second part I cant wrap my head around how you get $-m\textbf{S}(\dot{\textbf{q}}+\textbf{S}(\omega)\textbf{q})$

I also have to show that the Euler-Lagrange equations consequently becomes

$$m(\ddot{\textbf{q}}+2\textbf{S}(\omega)\dot{\textbf{q}}+\textbf{S}(\omega)\textbf{S}(\omega)\textbf{q}+\textbf{S}(\dot{\omega})\textbf{q})+\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{q}}V(\textbf{Rq})=0$$

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Guy3141 came with a super answer so the question is already partly solved, but..
When I doint the partial derivative for q I get

$$\frac{\partial L(\textbf{q},\dot{\textbf{q}})}{\partial \textbf{q}}=m\textbf{S}(\dot{\textbf{q}}+\textbf{S}(\omega)\textbf{q})-\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{q}}V(\textbf{Rq})$$

and I dont get the minus sign in front of the right hand side. Can anyone explain where the minus gets into the equation?

**EDIT EDIT**
I've been told to write everything in coordinates so that $q=(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ should do the trick and show why the minus sign is there, but I still don't see where the minus sign comes from :( Anyone able to help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about we write $$|\dot{\mathbf{q}}+\mathbf{S}q|^2=\langle\dot{\mathbf{q}}+\mathbf{S}q,\dot{\mathbf{q}}+\mathbf{S}q \rangle$$
and use rule for differentiating an inner product.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that! Thanks alot! :)

Comment: anytime, I love Lagrangian mechanics.  If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it so we can close the question.  Have a good day.

Comment: I certainly am! I got the equations done now and just have to show that the Euler-Lagrange equations becomes m(q''+2S... ... =0, which i am working on now :)

Comment: Actually you might be able to help me with the partial derivative of q. I just saw that there is a minus in front of the equation which I didnt get when I did the differentiation :/ I simply arrive at the equation without the minus sign.